# Inactive Plugin Files

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, backup

One of my plugins have some files that are inactive. I did some googling and found out that this is caused by editing files while the plugin is still active. *OOPS, guilty.*

I then deactivated and deleted the plugin and reinstalled it. But the same files are still displayed inactive. Now according to this, [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178896/how-can-i-reactivate-php-files-within-a-wp-plugin-that-have-been-marked-inac), the files will be inactive and the only meaningful file is the main plugin file. However, when I try to edit CSS file which is inactive, the changes does not reflect on the front end.

What should I do? The plugin was developed by my developer in which he may have provided me with a copy of the broken plugin when I told him the problem instead of the original backup. (He may not even have the 'original' backup)

Comment: you shouldn't edit live php files with the editor, but CSS files won't cause a fatal error, so it doesn't really matter if it's active or not. when you say the changes do not reflect on the front end, do you mean you view the file source and don't see the changes?

Comment: @Milo for example, if I were to edit the CSS or .php (plugin deactivated of course), the changes are not reflected on the front end. The changes I've made are 'more' noticeable in that it is for example in CSS: the color, in the php, the name of a form label. Am I doing something wrong or is it in my belief that since I broke the plugin in the first place, it is broken even though I've reinstalled it again. And as stated above, it is my belief that the plugin backup is the backup of the plugin broken when I've edited it without deactivating the plugin.